# Unable to publish single jar in multi project using gradle

Tags: java, gradle

The structure of multi project is

```
Root 
 +---ProjectA
     +---ProjectB
     +---ProjectC
     +    ...
```

I want to publish a single consolidated jar file in

```
task allJar
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
      url "myurl"
      credentials {
        // Credentials needed to pull build dependencies from Nexus
        username "$username"
        password "$password"
      }
    }
  }

}


apply plugin: "maven-publish"
apply plugin: "maven"

allprojects {

  repositories {
      mavenLocal()
      maven {
        credentials {
          username "$username"
          password "$password"
        }
        url "url"
      }

    group 'com.myproject'
    version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

  }

  subprojects {
   apply plugin: 'java'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    sourceSets.main.java.srcDir "src/main/java"
    sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs "src/main/resources"
    sourceSets.test.java.srcDir "src/test/java"
    sourceSets.test.resources.srcDirs "src/test/resources"
    dependencies {

      // string utils
      compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4"
      testCompile "junit:junit"

    }
    compileJava.dependsOn(processResources)
  }

}

subprojects.each { subproject ->
  evaluationDependsOn(subproject.path)
}
task allJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: subprojects.assemble) {
  baseName = project.name
  subprojects.each { subproject ->
    from subproject.configurations.archives.artifacts.files.collect {
      zipTree(it)
    }
  }
}


publishing {
  publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
      artifactId = project.name
      from components.java
      artifact allJar
      println "Project Group: " + project.group + "\nProject Name: " + project.name + "\nProject Version: " + project.version
    }
  }

  repositories {
    maven {
      credentials{

        username NEXUS_USER
        password NEXUS_PASS
      }

      url "myurl"

    }
  }
}
```

**Problems**

I am getting error during publish as

```
Invalid publication 'mavenJava': multiple artifacts with the identical extension and classifier ('jar', 'null
').
```

Adding a classifier :'all' in task allJar solves the issue but it creates 2 jars in root folder

1. build/libs/MyProject-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
2. build/libs/MyProject-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar

Comment: Not sure why this has a 'maven' tag.  It's clearly a gradle issue

Comment: Are you trying to create an uber-jar, so that dependents of your library would pull only a single dependency?
If so, take a look at the [shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow). I would create yet another subproject, which depends on all the subprojects that you'd like to include in the -all jar, and declare all these projects with the shadow configuration. The artifact of this new subproject would be the desired aggregated jar.